# Modify correct answer when OP was wrong

Tags: support

Is there a policy to modify the answer of an OP, when he obviously picked the wrong answer. Or will the correct answer get to the top when it gets enough votes?

Comment: Well, the problem has two solutions, I guess, and he picked an unsecure way of solving the issue.

Comment: I would leave a short comment expressing my view on the answer and why I believe the other one to be better.

Comment: @grm If the answer is so bad, it usually has a warning banner on it. Feel free to add such a banner if it doesn't have one already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, there is not.

Only the OP may change the accepted answer because the "accepted answer" is defined as the *"answer which worked for the OP"*.

If the accepted answer is wrong or incorrect, voting will determine it's actual credibility. There are many cases in which an unaccepted answer has higher votes than the accepted one, which is perfectly fine.

References:

- [Is it possible to change the chosen answer? - Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120569/232872)
- [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"? - Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: So the real correct answer will eventually get to the top? The OP is maybe ignorant here, and he has chosen the insecure way of solving the issue (the 2. answer in the list is the most up-voted by far)

Comment: @grm The accepted answer will always be 'pinned' to the top. The only difference is that if there is a significant difference in votes, it's obvious which is better.

Comment: ok, that sounds very clever. Will just give it some time then. Thank you!

Comment: There is a situation where an answer with more votes than the accepted answer is shown at the top: When the accepted answer is a [self-answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). Plus, users choose whether to view posts in "ACTIVE," "OLDEST," or "VOTES" order. Generally the order that posts are shown shouldn't be relied upon (for that reason, and because votes could change, or an OP could even unaccept one answer and accept another). *Any* answer that recommends an insecure solution without explaining the insecurity should be constructively commented on, even if it has very low score.

Comment: @grm See [Eliah's comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8121/modify-correct-answer-when-op-was-wrong/8122?noredirect=1#comment14527_8122) about when the accepted answer may not be on the top.